# Chrome autocompleted fields not recognized

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

Is Chrome auto-complete actually a total mess or am I just using it wrong?

Been having issues where I'll go to a web page, Chrome appears to do a good job of auto-completing fields (edit boxes?) for me, but the web site doesn't realize the data has been entered.  The edit boxes have yellow backgrounds and the "Sign in" or "Continue" or whatever button I need to click to commit the data remains grayed out.  I then have to click in each field, enter one character and delete it, then the field turns white instead of yellow and the web site allows me to proceed.  Today this is happening and I notice it is auto-filling a username and password.  Not sure if this affects the problem vs auto-filling for example my address.

There are other times when my forms are auto-filled, remain colored yellow, but seem to work fine.  Should one expect the fields to be yellow or white after they are auto-filled?

I do have other issues with the auto-fill feature but I'll leave those for a separate post in an effort to remain focused here.

Comment: I've never had this problem. What website is it happening on? Has auto-complete ever worked on that site before?

Comment: https://wellsoffice.wellsfargo.com/portal/signon/I can't remember if it ever worked on this site.

Comment: As I expected, the website is the reason for the autocomplete not working. I did a quick inspect on the input fields and they have [autocomplete="off"](https://imgur.com/wCZph4J)

Comment: Thank you DrZoo!  If your comment was entered as an "answer" I would credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason autocomplete does not work on the site is because of the [implementation of `autocomplete="off"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc1Ze.jpg) in the `<input>` tag. I'm not sure why the developers of the site decided to implement this, but they must have a legitimate reason for doing so.